# LED voltage indicator - why don't these LEDs blow?

Tags: voltage-measurement, zener

I want to make a simple voltage indicator for my 75VDC power supply.  I was thinking one LED for ~12V, one for ~40V, and one for 70+V.  I found this simple [instructable online](https://www.instructables.com/id/LED-voltage-range-indicator/), which, for 3V-30V, turns on different LEDs.  They just put the leds all in parallel with differently sized zener diodes, very simple.  However, what I don't get is, why do the lower voltage LEDs not blow/burn up/etc when the voltage becomes higher?  It seems like if you had a 2.2V LED with a 1V zener diode, then once the voltage got up to 30V, this 2.2V LED would have 29V going through it?

Comment: a circuit based around LM3915 would work better here (if you can find 5-15V to run it from somewhere) but it's probably cheaper to just use an off the shelf  voltage display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LEDs **are not** in parallel with Zener diodes, instead they are in series and also in series with 12k current-limiting resistors.
With a 30V supply, a 2.2V LED in series with 1.2V Zener diode and 12k resistor has a current of (30V - 2.2V - 1.2V)/12k= 2.2mA which is fairly dim since most 5mm LEDs have a max allowed current of 30mA.

Comment: I didn't mean to word it as saying that each led+zener is in parallel, I meant that each led+zener+resistor circuit is in parallel

Comment: so the reason it 'works' is just because all the leds are running at such low current that even the highest voltage level doesn't damage them?

Comment: yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

They’re using 12K ohm for the load resistors, which will limit the current even for the lowest LED to less than a few mA.

It’s kind of a dumb circuit really: the LED brightness for the upper voltages will be dim.